# Reinitialise scrollspy angularStrap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-strap, scrollspy

I am using scrollspy from [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##scrollspy) to display the current month while scrolling. The title loop where the scrollspy is initiated:

```
<h1>
  <span ng-repeat="month in months" data-target="#month{{month}}" bs-scrollspy>
</h1>
```

The elements that are being spied are table rows:

```
<table>
  <tr id="month{{dateOfCoordinate(week,0).format('YYYYM')}}" ng-repeat="week in weeks">
    <td ng-repeat="day in range(0,6)">
      FooBar
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This all works fine until I remotely add more weeks and months. The scrollspy does not work with the newly added elements while the generated html looks fine. In the scrollspy module ([GitHub](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/dist/modules/scrollspy.js)), the spy is initiated with $scrollspy.init. I guess I have to reinitialise the scrollspy again with the $scrollspy service but I could not get it working. Thanks